# Java Chat system protocol design, how to determine message type?

Tags: java, chat, protocols

I have a chat program implemented in Java. The client can send lots of different types of information to the server (i.e, Joins the server and sends username, password; requests a private chat with another user on the server, disconnects from the server, etc).

I'm looking for the correct way to have the server/client differentiate between 'text' messages that are just meant to be chat text messages sent from one client to the others, and 'command' messages (disconnect, request private chat, request file transfer, etc) that are meant for the server or the client.

I see two options:

1. Use serialized objects, and determine what they are on the receiving end by doing an 'instanceof'
2. Send the data as a byte array, reserving the first N bytes of the array to specify the 'type' of the incoming data.

What is the 'correct' way to do this? How to real protocols (oscar, irc) handle this situation?

I've googled around on this topic and only found examples/discussions centering on simple java chat applications. None that go into detail about protocol design (which I ultimately intend to practice).

Thanks to any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second approach is much better, because serialization is a complex mechanism, that can be easily used in a wrong way (for example you may bind yourself to internal content of a concrete serialized class). Plus your protocol will be bound to JVM mechanism. 
Using some "protocol header" for message differentiation is a common way in network protocols (FTP, HTTP, etc). It is even better when it is in a text form (people will be able to read it).

Comment: The whole binding to the JVM impl hadn't occured to me... That seems to me like a very good reason to avoid serialization in this case. - Thanks

Comment: Ah, well serialization is a common concept. You obviously don't have to go with *Javas built-in* searlization! Having one class per message type is still quite elegant. Have a look at [KryoNet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) for instance.

Comment: I checked out KryoNet - they are in fact using the instance of technique and serializing their objects etc... If I were to go this route, how would you suggest I lay out my build environment to keep the objects that are shared between server and client together, so as to avoid having to change "SomeObject" in both the server and client trunks? Can SomeObject be packaged with Server and Client builds?

Answer (score 2):

You typically have a little message header identifying the type of content in *all* messages, including standard text/chat messages.

Either of your two suggestions are fine. (In your second approach, you probably want to reserve some bytes for the *length* of the array as well.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Suppose the first thing in every header is the length specifier. I read in a length '10', saying there will be 10 bytes in my message. At an implementation level, I could use something like: int numBytesRead = read(buf, offset, len);... - should I read in the length as its own call to 'read'? This way I know how many bytes to attempt to read from the client when using read(buf, offset, len);

Comment: Something like that. I would do `int len = dataInputStream.readInt(); byte[] data = new byte[len]; dataInputStream.readFully(data);`.

Comment: Thanks! Is this sort of thing analogous to how oscar/IRC would do it? I've looked for their API's, but most things end up pointing me to libPurple (pidgin's oscar implementation). If you know of any good references to those API's that describe the actual messages sent across the network, I would be greatful.

Comment: IRC uses ASCII, i.e. sends text and numbers as characters and delimits data with new-line characters and doesn't rely on binary data. If you go for such approach, you could even use a `Scanner` to read the packets :-) But sure, in the end they have "headers" telling how the comming bytes/characters should be interpreted and/or what the intention of the message is.

Comment: Thanks aioobe (I've used that variable name many times to point to exceptions). I will create a header format then, I suppose using statically defined constants shared between client and server to represent semantics in the messages will make the most sense.